# Is there a way to find a not least-squares solution for system of linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am coming from a non-mathematical background, so my question might be completely nonsensical; excuse me if it actually is.

After playing around with machine learning, I have found out that there are a number of different "loss functions" that one can use to dramatically change the performance of the model on certain datasets.

Let's say you are given an overdetermined and inconsistent system of linear equations in matrix form. The goal is to approximate the solution to $Ax=b$. All the methods I have found so far will minimize the squared error $(e)^2$, but is there a way to find a solution, that would be minimizing the $\log(\cosh(e))$ or just a simple $|e|$?

Comment: Sometimes people minimize $\| Ax - b \|_1$ rather than $\| Ax - b \|_2^2$. Minimizing $\| Ax - b \|_1$ is an example of "robust linear regression".

Comment: @littleO thank you for the lead, I need to read up quite a bit more about it, but so far it looks exactly like what I need.